# Node.JS MongoDB find: Sequential faster than parallel, why?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have encountered a strange behaviour that contradicts what I thought I'd know about mongodb:

I have 4 empty collections. I do a `find` on each collection and measure, how long the queries will take until being fulfilled.

For the "parallel"-test, I start all queries using `await Promise.all(queries)`. For the "sequential"-test, I start all queries using "await queries[0..3]".

I would expect that, due to the collections being empty, the measured times are in general quite low, with the parallel request executing a bit faster than the sequential one. The queries go towards localhost - meaning that transporting the data from the client to the mongodb server and back should not add much overhead.

However; the results:

> parallel: **2008** ms
>
> sequential: **2** ms

Maybe my code has issues?

When I execute the queries multiple times in a loop, I receive the following results:

> Parallel 1: 2008.642 ms
>
> Sequential 1: 2.344 ms
>
> Parallel 2: 1004.544ms
>
> Sequential 2: 5.273ms
>
> Parallel 3: 2.152ms
>
> Sequential 3: 3.605ms
>
> Parallel 4: 2.189ms
>
> Sequential 4: 3.885ms

Whenever I restart the program, I receive similar results (with and without dropping/recreating the collections).

My question: *Why does the parallel queries need more time than the sequential ones?* And why do the parallel requests speed up with each request done, but reset the request duration when I restart the Node.JS software?

Due to the behaviour, I expect the reason to lay somewhere in my Node.JS code or in the MongoDB Node.JS driver.

My code:

```js
import {
    MongoClient,
    ObjectID,
} from 'mongodb';

const run = async () => {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase', {
            useNewUrlParser: true
        }),
        db = client.db('mydatabase'),
        userId = new ObjectID();

    // create collections
    await db.dropCollection('collection1');
    await db.dropCollection('collection2');
    await db.dropCollection('collection3');
    await db.dropCollection('collection4');
    await db.createCollection('collection1');
    await db.createCollection('collection2');
    await db.createCollection('collection3');
    await db.createCollection('collection4');

    // measure read fullfill times
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
        console.time(`Parallel ${i}`);
        await Promise.all([
                db.collection('collection1')
                    .find()
                    .toArray(),

                db.collection('collection2')
                    .find()
                    .toArray(),

                db.collection('collection3')
                    .find()
                    .toArray(),

                db.collection('collection4')
                    .find()
                    .toArray(),
        ]);
        console.timeEnd(`Parallel ${i}`);

        console.time(`Sequential ${i}`);
        await db.collection('collection1')
            .find()
            .toArray();

        await db.collection('collection2')
            .find()
            .toArray();

        await db.collection('collection3')
            .find()
            .toArray();

        await db.collection('collection4')
            .find()
            .toArray();
        console.timeEnd(`Sequential ${i}`);
    }
};

run();
```

The compiled code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/ETmPPbzd

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Due to the behaviour, I expect the reason to lay somewhere in my Node.JS code or in the MongoDB Node.JS driver.

Yes, you're right! It's within the mongo-client pool. When you first create the pool, it has a single connection. When you ask 4 requests at once, it tries opening up more connections and generally seems to get into a bad state. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/core/driver/reference/pool/

If you set your `poolSize` to 1 for your connection, you should see similar performance between parallel & serial. There's also a [`minSize` option](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/3b6957dbd2f985b3442b238b696debb89f668df5/lib/mongo_client.js#L111) that will initialize the connection pool with the appropriate number of connections & ensure that the pool-size never dips below the minimum size.

Comment: I can confirm that setting (in my case) `poolSize` to 1 adjusts the performance. It seems that the delay comes from the driver initializing the connection pool, which takes time and causes the first parallel requests to take longer. However, I could not find any way to initialize the pools without doing pooling myself.

Comment: Assuming your traffic isn't super bursty, you can have your mongo connection code do some arbitrary requests to force the client to open up enough connections. Once those initial requests complete, you can assume that pool is "initialized." You can even increase your socket timeout to make sure that connections stay open for long enough -- http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/core/driver/reference/pool/ (It's definitely not a great solution -- the node mongo-client seems to have some warts. I'd love to know if there's a better approach)

Comment: @MartinBories, I poked around in the mongo-client code a little bit and found a `minSize` option that should be a better way to handle this. I ran a load test, and it did speed things up the way that you'd expect!